# How to use Google Speech API Asynchronous Speech Recognition in Android

Tags: java, android, api, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I want to convert recorded audio files speech to text. I'm trying to use Google Speech API using **Asynchronous Speech Recognition**.

I have few question on how to proceed.

**1 .** I want to convert audio text and don't want it in real-time. So I should use Asynchronous recgonition ?  
[Google sample project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/SpeechService.java) uses **SpeechGrpc**. Is it necessary to use in android *ASychronous speech recognition*? Or I can use **SpeechClient** After authentication ..How?

**2 .** **SpeechGrpc** `(com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc)` is not present in my package ! (com.google.cloud.speech.v1). I'll have to install it from here? [grpc.io](http://grpc.io)

**3 .** I used Google Cloud Platform Console API key to authenticate to the Speech API (*ManagedChannel* object) but I cant understand how to use it and which function to use for Asynchronous Speech Recognition.

```
// Authentication 

try {
                GoogleCredentials creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
                creds = creds.createScoped(SCOPE);
                mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT)
                        .intercept(new ClientAuthInterceptor(creds, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()))
                        .build();
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create channel.", e);
            }
```

So what should I do after authentication. Is there any code reference or documentation for Asynchronous Speech Recognition in android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to use Asynchronous request.

You need to upload files to google cloud storage if they are longer than a minute.
https://cloud.google.com/speech/quotas
"* Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage."

I use the implementation on the sample project and it works pretty well, i would recommend using SpeechGrpc with longRunningRecognize for the request.

You can use the json credential file if using SpeechGrpc by reading the file stream and then using GoogleCredentials to authenticate.